# Is there a RestSharp implementation that works with Portable Class Libraries?

Tags: restsharp, portable-class-library

When I try to add RestSharp to a portable class library project using nuget, I get the following:

> Could not install package 'RestSharp 104.1'. You are trying to install
>   this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETPortable,Version=v4.0,Profile=Profile104', but the package does
>   not contain any assembly references or content files that are
>   compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the
>   package author.

I assume then it is not supported? If that be the case anyone have any suggestions on how to get this to work?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13547479/are-there-any-rest-libraries-out-there-that-work-with-portable-class-libraries

Answer (score 5):

Another interesting option is [Flurl](https://flurl.io)

> Flurl is a modern, fluent, asynchronous, testable, portable, buzzword-laden URL builder and HTTP client library.

Code snippet:

```
var result = await "https://api.mysite.com"
    .AppendPathSegment("person")
    .SetQueryParams(new { a = 1, b = 2 })
    .WithOAuthBearerToken("my_oauth_token")
    .PostJsonAsync(new { first_name = "Frank", last_name = "Underwood" })
    .ReceiveJson<T>();
```

Answer (score 4):

You have a portable RestSharp working at:

https://github.com/Geodan/geoserver-csharp/tree/master/RestSharp

It seems it's working well... It uses Json.net portable version too

Comment: I'm unsure how to import this into Xamarin Studio.  I have downloaded the branch, and added it as a new project, but it is unable to build because it missing almost every reference: `Microsoft.Threading.Tasks`, `Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extension`, `System.IO`, etc.  Any point in the right direction?

Comment: @edthethird I added this to my PCL using the NuGet package. I did have to add Microsoft.Bcl.Build myself because adding the RestSharp.Portable package didn't manage to add the former (although it tried). Once I added the ...Bcl.Build package myself, I was able to add RestSharp.Portable.

Answer (score 2):

You may try [RestSharp.Portable](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FubarCoder.RestSharp.Portable/). This is a library which offers an API very similar to RestSharp.

Comment: Yes. This is an alternative to RestSharp

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to look at [PortableRest](https://github.com/advancedrei/PortableRest). Again, provides similar capabilities (and adheres closely to the API style) to RestSharp for .NET 4.5, Silverlight 5, Windows Phone 8.x, and Windows 8.x, as well as iOS and Android through Xamarin.