# Are there any REST libraries out there that work with Portable Class Libraries?

Tags: c#, rest, portable-class-library

I am developing a portable class library that needs to make REST requests and am looking for something like Restsharp or EasyHttp. Unfortunately neither of these currently work with PCLs. It would also be nice to either see an example that does a post request with basic authentication.

If there is nothing out does anyone have an example of how I would do a post request with basic authentication?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you target 4.5 or Windows Store apps you can use HttpClient as PCL. Otherwise you can try the hack and slash PCL port of RestSharp at https://github.com/Geodan/geoserver-csharp/tree/master/RestSharp

Comment: i thought that HttpClient was not in Windows Store app framework yet and that it was coming with the windows blue release this summer ?

Answer (score 2):

There is one that was just recently announced and is currently available on GitHub. It's called Portable Rest

https://github.com/advancedrei/PortableRest

> PortableRest is a Portable Class Library for implementing REST API
>   clients in other Portable Class Libraries. It leverages JSON.NET for
>   rapid, customizable serialization, as well as the Microsoft.Bcl.Async
>   library for awaitable execution on any platform. It is designed to be
>   largely drop-in compatible with RestSharp, though you will need to
>   make some changes and recompile.
>
> This initial release has limited support for simple JSON requests.
>   More options (including XML and hopefully DataContract support) will
>   be available in later releases.

Answer (score 1):

Since I was only supporting windows phone 7.5 and higher I was able to use this library ([Microsoft.Bcl.Async](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/11/22/10361314.aspx?PageIndex=3)) to add async suppport to my plc and then use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565090/getting-the-response-of-a-asynchronous-httpwebrequest/10565229).

So my code ended up looking like this:

```
 public async Task<RequestResult> RunRequestAsync(string requestUrl, string requestMethod, object body = null)
    {
        HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
        req.ContentType = "application/json";

        req.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(User, Password);

        string auth = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", User, Password)));
        var authHeader = string.Format("Basic {0}", auth);
        req.Headers["Authorization"] = authHeader;

        req.Method = requestMethod; //GET POST PUT DELETE
        req.Accept = "application/json, application/xml, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, text/xml";

        if (body != null)
        {
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body, new JsonSerializerSettings() { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
            byte[] formData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

            var requestStream = Task.Factory.FromAsync(
                req.BeginGetRequestStream,
                asyncResult => req.EndGetRequestStream(asyncResult),
                (object)null);

            var dataStream = await requestStream.ContinueWith(t => t.Result.WriteAsync(formData, 0, formData.Length));
            Task.WaitAll(dataStream);
        }

        Task<WebResponse> task = Task.Factory.FromAsync(
        req.BeginGetResponse,
        asyncResult => req.EndGetResponse(asyncResult),
        (object)null);

        return await task.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            var httpWebResponse = t.Result as HttpWebResponse;

            return new RequestResult
            {
                Content = ReadStreamFromResponse(httpWebResponse),
                HttpStatusCode = httpWebResponse.StatusCode
            };

        });
    }

    private static string ReadStreamFromResponse(WebResponse response)
    {
        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            //Need to return this response 
            string strContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
            return strContent;
        }
    }
```

And then I would call the code with something like:

```
public async Task<bool> SampleRequest()
        {            
            var res = RunRequestAsync("https//whatever.com/update/1", "PUT");
            return await res.ContinueWith(x => x.Result.HttpStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
```

If that wasn't enough code for you feel free to check out the rest of the project [here](https://github.com/eneifert/ZendeskApi_v2/blob/master/ZendeskApi_v2/Core.cs)

Answer (score 0):

You have a portable RestSharp working at:

https://github.com/Geodan/geoserver-csharp/tree/master/RestSharp

It seems it's working well... It uses Json.net to