# Using RestSharp cross-platform using Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.ios, cross-platform, xamarin.android, xamarin, restsharp

I'm using Xamarin to develop a cross-platform mobile app. To communicate with our REST-service I'd like to create a shared project between these platforms to have a service access layer. The problem is that RestSharp has different projects for different platforms. How can I create a shared project while still using the platform-specific libraries. Does that make sense?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13547479/are-there-any-rest-libraries-out-there-that-work-with-portable-class-libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this exact thing a few months ago. I ran into problems when trying to use my "Service Library" on WP8 because of the RestSharp dependency. If I had it to do over, I would do just like the link that @user1010710 mentioned in the comment and use `HttpClient`.