# Install the Twilio REST API Helper Library from Nuget can not support windows 8.1/.net 4.5.1

Tags: c#, twilio, windows-8.1, restsharp

I am trying to install twilio rest api helper library

And it give this message:

Attempting to resolve dependency 'RestSharp'.

Installing 'RestSharp 104.3.3'.

Successfully installed 'RestSharp 104.3.3'.

Installing 'Twilio 3.6.9'.

Successfully installed 'Twilio 3.6.9'.

Adding 'RestSharp 104.3.3' to Om.

Uninstalling 'RestSharp 104.3.3'.
Successfully uninstalled 'RestSharp 104.3.3'.

Install failed. Rolling back...

Could not install package 'RestSharp 104.3.3'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETCore,Version=v4.5.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545744/is-there-a-restsharp-implementation-that-works-with-portable-class-libraries?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

This messages need improvement but the failing to install is by design, as the RestSharp package does not seem to support windows store apps.

Please create an issue at nuget.codeplex.com. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

Are you trying to install into a Windows Store application.  If yes, currently there is no version of RestSharp that works with Windows Store applications.  The Twilio library depends on RestSharp.

There is currently ongoing work to create a Portable Class Library version of RestSharp (see https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/468).

Once this is stable we'll release a Twilio library built on it.

Hope that helps.